# Error 'BinaryToArray' in undefined in CRM 2015

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, vbscript, dynamics-crm-2015

There was a working [solution](http://xrmmatrix.blogspot.sk/2011/06/creating-report-as-pdf-attachment-in.html) to generate pdf from SSRS report and attach in email in CRM 2013 version. But unfortunately since CRM 2015 version this solution has stopped working due to vbscript function call via javascript function.

Here is the sample code where it is throwing error. Help would be much appreciated.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function encodePdf(params) {
            bdy = new Array();
            bdyLen = 0;
            var retrieveEntityReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var pth = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=" + params[0] + "&Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=" + params[1] + "&OpType=Export&FileName=Public&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=PDF";
            retrieveEntityReq.open("GET", pth, false);
            retrieveEntityReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");

            retrieveEntityReq.send();
            **BinaryToArray(retrieveEntityReq.responseBody);**
            return encode64(bdy);
        }
</script>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Function BinaryToArray(Binary)
       Dim i
       ReDim byteArray(LenB(Binary))
       For i = 1 To LenB(Binary)
              byteArray(i-1) = AscB(MidB(Binary, i, 1))
              concat2Bdy(AscB(MidB(Binary, i, 1)))
       Next
       BinaryToArray = byteArray
End Function
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error it is throwing?

Comment: I don't know if it's the whole truth but change "getServerUrl" to "getClientUrl", getServerUrl is deprecated as of CRM 2011 UR 12-ish IIRC